# Current record with group by function

Tags: sql

Trying to get userid recent aggregate value for session_id.

(session_id 3 has two records, recent agg value is 80.00
 session_id 4 has four records, recent agg value is 95.00
 session_id 6 has three records, recent agg value is 72.00

Table:session_agg

```
id session_id userid    agg      date
-- ---------- ------  -----    -------
 1         3     11    60.00   1573561586
 4         3     11    80.00   1573561586
 6         4     11    35.00   1573561749 
 7         4     11    50.00   1573561751
 8         4     11    70.00   1573561912
 10        4     11    95.00   1573561921
 11        6     14    40.00   1573561945
 12        6     14    67.00   1573561967
 13        6     14    72.00   1573561978   

select id, session_id, userid, agg, date from session_agg 
WHERE date IN (select MAX(date) from session_agg GROUP BY session_id) AND
userid = 11
```

Comment: you have used agg instead of add column

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your current approach, then you need to correlate the `session_id` in the subquery which checks for the max date for each session:

```
SELECT id, session_id, userid, add, date
FROM session_agg sa1
WHERE
    date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM session_agg sa2 WHERE sa2.session_id = sa1.session_id) AND
    userid = 11;
```

But, if your version of SQL supports analytic functions, `ROW_NUMBER` is an easier way to do this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM session_agg
)

SELECT id, session_id, userid, add, date
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen Thank You.